# Display CameraInfo/Image message with frame_id != fixed frame

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, plugin, librviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I've tried to display multiple CameraInfo/Image messages within rviz. I have tf_broadcasters, publishing the camera transformations with about 50 Hz.

My CameraInfo/Image messages have different frame_id's and I want to visualize them with rviz' default plugin. However, a camera image only shows up if the global fixed frame is equal to the image frame_id. Specifically, the warning within the plugin is :

1. `No CameraInfo received on [/sensor/camera/st_front_right_rect/camera_info].  Topic may not exist.`
2. `No Image received`

At first, I thought this could happen because of tf, but this seems to be fine.

My tf tree, visualized via `view_frames`  looks fine (one root, with several leaves). In particular, doing a `rosrun tf tf_monitor camera_rig_calibration st_front_left_rect` gives me

```
RESULTS: for camera_rig_calibration to st_front_left_rect
Chain is: camera_rig_calibration -> st_front_left_rect
Net delay     avg = 0.0161706: max = 0.223564

Frames:
Frame: st_front_left_rect published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.00131894 Max Delay: 0.030248
```

Doing a `rostopic echo /sensor/camera/st_front_left_rect/image_rect/header` gives me for the **Image/header**:

```
seq: 1077
stamp: 
  secs: 18980
  nsecs: 802162648
frame_id: st_front_left_rect
```

and `rostopic echo /sensor/camera/st_front_left_rect/cameraInfo/header` for the **CameraInfo/Header**:

```
seq: 1077
stamp: 
  secs: 18980
  nsecs: 802162456
frame_id: st_front_left_rect
```

However, I cannot visualize the image for fixed frame `camera_rig_calibration`.

Any ideas, how I could further debug? Thanks in advance for any help provided!

What could be other reasons for the CameraInfo/Image not showing up? I can provide further code if desired.

Regards,
Sascha

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226694/display-camerainfo/image-message-with-frame_id-!=-fixed-frame/) by [sascha](https://answers.ros.org/users/25952/sascha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my problem using the `tf2_ros::StaticTransformPublisher` for publishing the transformation graph.

I guess my problem was that transfomations and cameras were published in two different processes and thus had slightly different stamps.

---

Originally posted by [sascha](https://answers.ros.org/users/25952/sascha/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a fully connected tf tree, the images should show up. If displaying only works when setting the fixed frame to the camera frame, the most likely causes are either the tf tree being not fully connected or timestamps of images and tf data not matching up.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sascha](https://answers.ros.org/users/25952/sascha/) on 2016-02-15**:
Hi Stefan,

thanks for your quick reply. A wrong TF configuration was also my guess. I edited my original post and included some info on it. Do you have any recommendations on how to further inspect it?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-02-15**:
Try `roswtf`

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-02-15**:
The timestamp for your image and camera info message are not equal, this might also be problematic.